# Delete the last append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to delete the last append when i click the back button. but when Im choosing appending again,the last append still there.

this is my codes on appending. its working:

```
$(req.responseText).find('ItemName').each(function () {
    ItemNameArr[ItName] = $(this).text();
    ItName++;
})                  

$(req.responseText).find('ItemQty').each(function () {
    ItemQtyArr[ItQty] = $(this).text();
    ItQty++;
})         

$(req.responseText).find('ItemUnit').each(function () {
    ItemUnitArr[ItUn] = $(this).text();
    ItUn++;
})

for (var a = 0; a < ItemNameArr.length; a++) {
   //$contentDt = $('<p><h6> ' + ItemQtyArr[a] + " " + ItemUnitArr[a] + " " + ItemNameArr[a] + '</h6></p>');                              
    $('#Ingredients').append('<p><h6> ' + ItemQtyArr[a] + " " + ItemUnitArr[a] + " " + ItemNameArr[a] + '</h6></p>')
    $('#Ingredients').fieldcontain('refresh')
 }
```

My codes in back button when its click:

```
  $("#btnBack").on('click',function(){
     $('#Ingredients').empty()
      $('#Ingredients').fieldcontain('refresh')

  });
```

My codes in html when it was append

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="Ingredients">    <!--Ingridients-->

 </div>    

   });
```

Comment: $('p').last().remove() ?

Comment: You need to provide us with your page layout. All answers below are a correct one, you are just not using them in a appropriate moment.

Comment: yes plz provide complete page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using below code.

```
$('#Ingredients p:last').remove();
```

Comment: still getting the last append sir..i put ur code in the back button

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code

```
$('#Ingredients p:last').remove();
```

> **Explanation**

`#` referees for the id selector.

`$('#Ingredients p)` finds the p tag in the element with id Ingredients.

`$('#Ingredients p:last')` selects last p tag in the element with id Ingredients.

`.remove()` function removes it from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your back button code (click event)

it will be -

```
$("html").on('click','#btnBack',function(){

      // your code

      // for remove last p element within #Ingredients
      $('#Ingredients p:last').remove();
});
```